# How to use comma instead dot in TextField on Samsung Galaxy with Flutter/Dart

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to build a TextField for numbers in Flutter/Dart.

For decimal numbers, I want to use commas instead of dot ( = Germany).

[image]

I detected the problem with Samsung Galaxy S5 and S6.

On other Smartphones with GBoard installed, there is both, command and dot,  available.

Does anyone else have this problem?

keyboardType:

```
TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true,),
```

Comment: which locale you are currently using?

Comment: yes i tried the following: 
```
return MaterialApp(
  supportedLocales: [
 const Locale("de", "DE"),
  ],
  locale: Locale("de", "DE"),
  localizationsDelegates: [
 GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
 GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
  ],
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding extra row to the android default keyboard is not possible for this you have to go to the custom keyboard.

[You can check custom keyboard example here](https://github.com/rciovati/Android-KeyboardView-Example)

Comment: I want to do this with Flutter, not "Default-Android-Java/Kotlin"

Comment: Try phone number as input type.